# Solenoid stays on when output turned off

Tags: solid-state-relay, solenoid, output, plc

I have a power supply with 12V running into a the common on my PLC. Output 0 on the PLC is wired into a solenoid. The negative on the solenoid runs into the ground on the power supply completing the circuit.

When I power up the PLC and the the external power supply all outputs on the PLC are off and the solenoid is off. When I activate Output 0, my solenoid clicks on as expected. However, when I turn Output 0 back off, the solenoid stays on. The solenoid only turns off if I physically remove the ground wire.

**edit:**

The diagram below gives some insight. Power supply wired to Pin 17. Output 0 (pin 10) wired to solenoid. Solenoid is wired back to ground on the power supply.

If I give the command to turn output 0 on, the solenoid comes on. If I give the command to turn output 0 off, the solenoid stays on.

[image]

Link to my cheapo solenoid. [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008IG7SWQ/ref=oh_details_o04_s00_i01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008IG7SWQ)

Comment: Ben, what model SSR (solid state relay) are you using?  What you are describing is consistent with a situation when an SSR made for AC is used for DC.

Comment: @Nick: He said "solenoid" and that he heard a click, both of which are inconsitant with a solid state relay.  Otherwise, that was a clever insight, but unfortunately doesn't apply here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  `solid-state-relay` seems to be among the tags.  At the same time, if Ben posted a diagram of what he is attempting, that wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, initially I had the PS running through a SSR and was using the PLC to energize the SSR, turning the solenoid (which had the same issue). I then removed the SSR and went directly into the PLC with the solenoid to simplify troubleshooting and had the same result.

Comment: Basically no matter what I try, once the output is turned on the solenoid is energized it stays energized until I disconnect a wire. I cant turn the output off to turn the solenoid off. Added a drawing to help.

Comment: Does this happen on other channels?

Comment: A lot of solenoids will stay on (once activated) almost down to zero mA flowing thru them. Try putting a 3.3kohm resistor in parallel with the solenoid and see what happens. It could be a few mA leakage thru the opto-transistor. Maybe provide a link to the solenoid too.

Comment: What's the model of the PLC you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions I researched my relay and found the outputs were AC. I spec'd a similar relay with DC outputs and everything worked as intended. Thanks for everyone's help.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

A common problem.  Its all to do with the coil on the device, I have had the same issue with energising contactors before.

Try instead to used the PLC output to energise a small relay and switch the solenoid via a relay contact.  That should solve your problem.